# Throwing Undefined plus the value in JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have a problem with this one. Instead of having a result of **uniqueID = value** I'm having a result like this **uniqueID = undefinedvalue**

JavaScript Code

```
function read(a){
var html;
 if(a.indexOf("http://") === 0 || a.indexOf("https://") === 0)
   html+="<a target='_blank' href='"+a+"'>"+a+"</a><br>";
   html+=htmlEntities(a);

   var audio = new Audio('lib/beep.ogg');
   audio.play();

   var uniqueID = document.getElementById("mapo").innerHTML= html;      

    window.location.href = "http://localhost/QR_JEFF/server.php?uniqueID=" + uniqueID;


}
```

PHP Code

```
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','suffrage');
        $uniqueID =  $_GET['uniqueID'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM applicant_table WHERE unique_id='$uniqueID'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {


      $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
      if($logged_in_user['validation_status'] == 'Verified' && $logged_in_user['voting_status'] == 'No'){

      $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $id;
      $_SESSION['validation_status'] = $logged_in_user;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";

      header('location: wow.html'); 

    }

  }
```

[This is the output in my URL. check this out to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dls3.png)

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: What is "mapo" is this a div or input box? <div id="mapo">Unique_ID</div> like this?

Comment: <div id="mapo"></div>  "mapo" is a div

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uniqueID = document.getElementById("mapo").innerText;
console.log(uniqueID);
/*var uniqueID = document.getElementById("mapo").value;*/
```

```html
<div id="mapo">123456789</div>
<!--<input id="mapo" type="hidden" value="123456789" />-->
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a login function using a qr code. I'm using LazarSoft qrcode.js

Comment: Could you please check what you're getting in console.log(uniqueID);

Comment: I already solve it the answer is right above. Thank you for entertaining my question. :)

Comment: @JeffNUCode Sry I saw it lately. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. This is the solution.

```
function read(a){

   var html=htmlEntities(a);

   var audio = new Audio('lib/beep.ogg');
   audio.play();

   var uniqueID = document.getElementById("mapo").innerHTML= html;      

    window.location.href = "http://localhost/QR_JEFF/server.php?uniqueID=" + uniqueID;

   }
```

I realized that the var=html dont have any value and when I concatenate it to my htmlEntities it resulted into an undefined index. So I remove it and place the htmlEntities straight to the var html. :)